# Accessing Link Button Text Present in Grid view column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, code-behind, telerik-grid

I have a Telerik GridView which contains several columns of which a few columns are link-buttons. I want to access the text of that link button upon clicking on it in code behind. I want to access only the particular column text which is clicked in code behind. My code is follows

```
<telerik:gridtemplatecolumn 
        datafield="EmployeeHRId" 
        filtercontrolalttext="Filter EmployeeHRId column"
        headertext="Employee HR ID" 
        sortexpression="EmployeeHRId" 
        uniquename="EmployeeHRId">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LBEmpHRId" runat="server"  
                EmpHRId='<%#Eval("EmployeeHRId") %>' 
                CssClass="EmpHrIdCss">
            <%#Eval("EmployeeHRId")%>
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</telerik:gridtemplatecolumn>
```

Please help me with this

Comment: What about a ForEach loop in the YourGrid.Items ?

Comment: on which event? a linkbutton click or RowCommand

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used TelerikGrid but the basic step is you will have to Find the control in the RowCommand event or similar that TelerikGrid exposed.

```
LinkButton lb = e.Item.FindControl("LBEmpHRId") as LinkButton;
string id = lb.Text;

//Alternately you can pass HRId as a CommandArgument of your LinkButton as well.
```

I found [this sample](http://kandydeol.blogspot.com/2013/08/get-row-value-on-button-click-in-radgrid.html) which says TelerikGrid has ItemCommand that you will have to handle.